# Callback to subset geometry data - dash Plotly

Tags: python, callback, plotly, plotly-dash, choropleth

I'm hoping to include a dropdown bar with a callback function that allows the user to display specific points within smaller areas. Initially, I want to use all point geometry data as a default. I'm then aiming to include a dropdown bar and callback function that returns smaller subsets from this main df. This is accomplished by merging the point data within a specific polygon area.

Using below, the default df is labelled `gdf_all`. This contains point data across a large region. The smaller polygon files are subset from `gdf_poly`. These include African and European continents. These are used within a function to only return point data if it intersects within the polygon shape.

I've hard-coded the outputs below. 1) uses `gdf_all` and 2) uses a subset from African contintent.

**Ideally, the dropdown bar will be used to input the desired point data to be visualised within the figures.**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

# point data
gdf_all = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))

# polygon data
gdf_poly = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
gdf_poly = gdf_poly.drop('name', axis = 1)

gdf_all['LON'] = gdf_all['geometry'].x
gdf_all['LAT'] = gdf_all['geometry'].y

# subset African continent
Afr_gdf_area = gdf_poly[gdf_poly['continent'] == 'Africa'].reset_index(drop = True)

# subset European continent
Eur_gdf_area = gdf_poly[gdf_poly['continent'] == 'Europe'].reset_index(drop = True)

# function to merge point data within selected polygon area
def merge_withinboundary(gdf1, gdf2):

    # spatial join data within larger boundary
    gdf_out = gpd.sjoin(gdf1, gdf2, predicate = 'within', how = 'left').reset_index(drop = True)

    return gdf_out

gdf_Africa = merge_withinboundary(gdf_all, Afr_gdf_area)
gdf_Europe = merge_withinboundary(gdf_all, Eur_gdf_area)


external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

# function to return selected df for plotting
def update_dataset(df):

    if df == 'gdf_Africa':
        gdf = gdf_Africa

    elif df == 'gdf_Europe':
        gdf = gdf_Europe

    else:
        gdf = gdf_all

    return gdf


nav_bar =  html.Div([
     html.P("area-dropdown:"),
     dcc.Dropdown(
       id='data', 
       value='data', 
       options=[{'value': 'gdf_all', 'label': 'gdf_all'},
            {'value': 'gdf_Africa', 'label': 'gdf_Africa'},
            {'value': 'gdf_Europe', 'label': 'gdf_Europe'}
            ],
       clearable=False
  ),
])

# output 1
df = gdf_all

# output 2
#df = gdf_Africa

scatter = px.scatter_mapbox(data_frame = df, 
                                   lat = 'LAT', 
                                   lon = 'LON',
                                   zoom = 2,
                                   mapbox_style = 'carto-positron', 
                                   )


count = df['name'].value_counts()

bar = px.bar(x = count.index, 
              y = count.values, 
              color = count.index, 
              )

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(nav_bar), width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure = scatter))
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure = bar))
            ]),
        ], width=5),
        dbc.Col([
        ], width=5),
    ])
], fluid=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port = 8051)
```

Output 1:

[image]

Output 2:

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand what is the functionality of dropdown list?

Comment: After concatenating all smaller dataframes into a bigger one. Do you want to visualize the entire dataframe after concatenation?

Comment: Didn't any answers below solve your problem?

Comment: I've got numerous figures/outputs in my dashboard. I'd like to update them _all_ at once with a dropdown. Rather than update the each individually

Comment: these answers did solve your problem, right?

Comment: No, they didn't. One returns a `ValueError`. The other partially answers it but I simplified my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main task is converting `update_dataset` into a callback function that takes the dropdown selection as an input, and outputs both the newly updated scatter mapbox and bar chart. In order to do this, you need to provide an `id` argument in `dcc.Graph` for both of those figures. Then inside the callback, you can recreate both the scatter mapbox and bar chart depending on the dropdown selection.

Also I am not sure about your use case, but for the purpose of this example, I modifed your `merge_withinboundary` function to perform an `inner join` instead of a left join (with the sample data you've provided, if you do a left join, you will always end up with `gdf_all` if that is the first argument to `merge_withinboundary` – because `Afr_gdf_area` and `Eur_gdf_area` are both completely contained inside `gdf_all`). However, I will leave that decision up to you – perhaps a left join is what you want for your actual data set.

For the purpose of this demonstration, I also set `zoom = 0` as the default, so when the user selects `gdf_all` from the dropdown, all of the points are visible.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

# point data
gdf_all = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))

# polygon data
gdf_poly = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
gdf_poly = gdf_poly.drop('name', axis = 1)

gdf_all['LON'] = gdf_all['geometry'].x
gdf_all['LAT'] = gdf_all['geometry'].y

# subset African continent
Afr_gdf_area = gdf_poly[gdf_poly['continent'] == 'Africa'].reset_index(drop = True)

# subset European continent
Eur_gdf_area = gdf_poly[gdf_poly['continent'] == 'Europe'].reset_index(drop = True)

# function to merge point data within selected polygon area
def merge_withinboundary(gdf1, gdf2):

    # spatial join data within larger boundary
    gdf_out = gpd.sjoin(gdf1, gdf2, predicate = 'within', how = 'inner').reset_index(drop = True)

    return gdf_out

gdf_Africa = merge_withinboundary(gdf_all, Afr_gdf_area)
gdf_Europe = merge_withinboundary(gdf_all, Eur_gdf_area)


external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

# function to return selected df for plotting
@app.callback(Output('scatter-mapbox', 'figure'),
              Output('bar', 'figure'),
              Input('data', 'value'),
              prevent_initial_call=True)
# function to return df using smaller areas
def update_dataset(dropdown_selection):
    if dropdown_selection == 'gdf_Africa':
        gdf = gdf_Africa
        zoom = 2

    elif dropdown_selection == 'gdf_Europe':
        gdf = gdf_Europe
        zoom = 2

    else:
        gdf = gdf_all
        zoom = 0

    scatter_subset = px.scatter_mapbox(data_frame = gdf, 
        lat = 'LAT', 
        lon = 'LON',
        zoom = zoom,
        mapbox_style = 'carto-positron', 
        )
    count = gdf['name'].value_counts()

    bar_subset = px.bar(x = count.index, 
                y = count.values, 
                color = count.index, 
                ) 
    return scatter_subset, bar_subset


nav_bar =  html.Div([
     html.P("area-dropdown:"),
     dcc.Dropdown(
       id='data', 
       value='data', 
       options=[{'value': 'gdf_all', 'label': 'gdf_all'},
            {'value': 'gdf_Africa', 'label': 'gdf_Africa'},
            {'value': 'gdf_Europe', 'label': 'gdf_Europe'}
            ],
       clearable=False
  ),
])

# output 1
df = gdf_all

# output 2
#df = gdf_Africa

scatter = px.scatter_mapbox(data_frame = df, 
                                   lat = 'LAT', 
                                   lon = 'LON',
                                   zoom = 0,
                                   mapbox_style = 'carto-positron', 
                                   )


count = df['name'].value_counts()

bar = px.bar(x = count.index, 
              y = count.values, 
              color = count.index, 
              )

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(nav_bar), width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure = scatter, id = 'scatter-mapbox'))
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure = bar, id = 'bar'))
            ]),
        ], width=5),
        dbc.Col([
        ], width=5),
    ])
], fluid=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port = 8051)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll try adapt this for my actual dataset. I was hoping to _not_ update the figures within the callback. I have a fair few outputs that will need to be incorporated. I should have put this in but I already have separate callback functions for these figures, independent of this new one

Comment: I believe it should be possible to use `plotly` alone to change data for dropdowns. If I get that working, I'll add that as an additional answer (since at this point, I think both of my answers are still worth leaving up as they could help someone with a similar problem to yours, but maybe fewer constraints). Also when you have the chance, please edit in some of those details so that you get answers as close as possible to what you're looking for – cheers

Comment: I'll add as a new question.

Comment: @Chopin that's fair – this question has gone through a lot of changes and has multiple answers. happy to take a look at your new question

Answer (score 2):

I have a partly working solution, but there's a lot of modifications that needs to be made. When you create a choropleth map using `px.choropleth`, the geojson argument must be a `(GeoJSON-formatted dict) – Must contain a Polygon feature collection, with IDs, which are references from locations` (from the [documentation](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.choropleth.html)) – passing `geojson = A_gdf_area` won't work because `A_gdf_area` is a `GeoDataFrame`.

In addition, your geojson file needs to have columns for the locations and colors in order to have colors on a choropleth map – I don't know which columns you are intending to use to color the map, so I have made up dummy columns called `ids` and `vals` that supply the locations and colors.

Since you are drawing regions in Italy (and px.choropleth only draws boundaries for countries of the world or states of the usa), you will need to first create a `go.Scattergeo` figure using `lats` and `lons` extracted from the geojson, and then add the choropleth data as a trace to this figure (credit for this idea goes to [this answer](https://community.plotly.com/t/in-choropleth-how-to-create-outline-for-country-and-differentiate-that-particular-countries-states/67013/6) on the plotly forum).

I have integrated this into a dash app below. The only thing is that the colors corresponding to the `vals` column don't seem to be rendering in the figure like I would expect – I will update this answer when I figure out why.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


gdf_area = gpd.read_file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/master/geojson/limits_IT_municipalities.geojson')

np.random.seed(42)
gdf_area['ids'] = np.random.choice([1,2,3], size=len(gdf_area))
gdf_area['vals'] = np.random.uniform(1, 10, size=len(gdf_area))

A_gdf_area = gdf_area[gdf_area['name'].str.startswith('A', na=False)][['name','geometry','ids','vals']]
B_gdf_area = gdf_area[gdf_area['name'].str.startswith('B', na=False)][['name','geometry','ids','vals']]
C_gdf_area = gdf_area[gdf_area['name'].str.startswith('C', na=False)][['name','geometry','ids','vals']]

dropdown_dict = {
    'A_gdf_area': A_gdf_area,
    'B_gdf_area': B_gdf_area,
    'C_gdf_area': C_gdf_area
}

def state_boundaries(geojdata):
    pts = []#list of points defining boundaries of polygons, pts has as coordinates the lon and lat
    for feature in geojdata['features']:
        if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'Polygon':
            pts.extend(feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0])    
            pts.append([None, None])#mark the end of a polygon   
        
        elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'MultiPolygon':
            for polyg in feature['geometry']['coordinates']:
                pts.extend(polyg[0])
                pts.append([None, None])#end of polygon
        elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'LineString': 
            pts.extend(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])
            pts.append([None, None])
        else: pass           
    #else: raise ValueError("geometry type irrelevant for map")
    lons, lats = zip(*pts) 
    return lons, lats

def create_choropleth_figure(gdf_area):
    geojson_string = gdf_area.to_json()
    geojson = json.loads(geojson_string)

    lons, lats = state_boundaries(geojson)
    fig = go.Figure(go.Scattergeo(lon=lons, lat=lats, mode="lines", line_width=1, line_color="black"))
    fig.update_layout(width=700, height=750,
        geo = dict(
            scope = 'europe',
            resolution = 110,  #for info help(go.layout.Geo.resolution)
            lataxis_range = [33, 48],
            lonaxis_range = [5, 20],
            landcolor = 'rgb(225, 225, 225)',
        ))

    reduced_geojson={"type": "FeatureCollection", "features":[]} 
    for feat in geojson["features"]:
        reduced_geojson["features"].append(feat)
    
    figc = px.choropleth(gdf_area, geojson=reduced_geojson, locations='ids', 
                                color="vals", color_continuous_scale="viridis")
    fig.add_trace(figc.data[0])
    return fig

def merge_withinboundary(gdf1, gdf2):

    # spatial join data within larger boundary
    gdf_out = gpd.sjoin(gdf1, gdf2, predicate = 'within', how = 'left').reset_index(drop = True)
    gdf_out['ids'] = gdf_out['ids_left']
    gdf_out['vals'] = gdf_out['vals_left']
    gdf_out.drop(columns=['ids_left','ids_right','vals_left','vals_right'], inplace=True)
    return gdf_out

gdf_A = merge_withinboundary(A_gdf_area, gdf_area)
fig = create_choropleth_figure(gdf_A)

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

nav_bar =  html.Div([
     html.P("area-dropdown:"),
     dcc.Dropdown(
       id='gdf', 
       value='Site', 
       options=[{'value': x, 'label': x} 
                for x in ['A_gdf_area', 'B_gdf_area', 'C_gdf_area']],
       clearable=False
   ),
])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(nav_bar), width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'choropleth-fig', figure = fig))
            ]),
        ], width=5),
        dbc.Col([
        ], width=5),
    ])
], fluid=True)

@app.callback(Output('choropleth-fig', 'figure'),
              Input('gdf', 'value'),
              prevent_initial_call=True)
def update_choropleth(dropdown_value):
    if dropdown_value is None:
        return dash.no_update
    
    selected_gdf_area = dropdown_dict[dropdown_value]
    new_gdf_area = merge_withinboundary(selected_gdf_area, gdf_area)
    
    fig = create_choropleth_figure(new_gdf_area)

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port = 8051)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Derek O. I modified the question to align with the data I have. There isn't a working example df but it may be easier to work with. Let me know if the question doesn't make sense

Comment: @Chopin your question is a little clearer than before, but it is somewhat difficult to work with because I need a data set to truly test your dash app – the samples of data that you've provided are helpful but too small to work with. I'll see what I can figure out

Comment: I've accounted for dummy data now @Derek O

Comment: thank you! i'll circle back on this question when i have some time later

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. This modifies the options list in the dropdown to include the names of the smaller data frames. Then, it creates a callback function that takes the selected value from the dropdown and uses it to filter the main data frame to get the corresponding smaller data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

gdf_area = gpd.read_file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/master/geojson/limits_IT_municipalities.geojson')

A_gdf_area = gdf_area[gdf_area['name'].str.startswith('A', na=False)][['name','geometry']]
B_gdf_area = gdf_area[gdf_area['name'].str.startswith('B', na=False)][['name','geometry']]
C_gdf_area = gdf_area[gdf_area['name'].str.startswith('C', na=False)][['name','geometry']]

def merge_withinboundary(gdf1, gdf2):
    # spatial join data within larger boundary
    gdf_out = gpd.sjoin(gdf1, gdf2, predicate = 'within', how = 'left').reset_index(drop = True)
    return gdf_out

gdf_A = merge_withinboundary(A_gdf_area, gdf_area)
gdf_B = merge_withinboundary(B_gdf_area, gdf_area)
gdf_C = merge_withinboundary(C_gdf_area, gdf_area)

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

nav_bar =  html.Div([
     html.P("area-dropdown:"),
     dcc.Dropdown(
       id='gdf', 
       value='A_gdf_area', 
       options=[{'value': 'A_gdf_area', 'label': 'A_gdf_area'},
                {'value': 'B_gdf_area', 'label': 'B_gdf_area'},
                {'value': 'C_gdf_area', 'label': 'C_gdf_area'}],
       clearable=False
   ),
])


@app.callback(
    Output('choropleth', 'figure'),
    Input('gdf', 'value')
)
def update_choropleth(selected_gdf):
    if selected_gdf == 'A_gdf_area':
        gdf = gdf_A
    elif selected_gdf == 'B_gdf_area':
        gdf = gdf_B
    else:
        gdf = gdf_C

    fig = px.choropleth(gdf, geojson=gdf.__geo_interface__, 
                        color='name',
                        color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Pastel)
    return fig


app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(nav_bar), width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id='choropleth'))
            ]),
        ], width=10),
    ])
], fluid=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8051)
```

So, it adds three new data frames gdf_A, gdf_B, and gdf_C, which are the result of calling merge_withinboundary on the corresponding smaller data frames. Also,  the options list in the dropdown is modified to include the names. Hope this helps!

Comment: this results in a `ValueError` – the app won't actually run